# What is the technique for sorting tuple in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, tuples

**Sorting criteria:**

*First emphasis whose first element is greater if collision occurs then second requirement is whose second element is lexicographically smallest.*

*List of tuples :*

```
a = [(100,'Rajan'),(200,'Anik'),(100,'Tanmoy')]
```

*Output :*

```
[(200,'Anik'),(100,'Rajan'),(100,'Tanmoy')]
```

*How it can be done with python ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort by a remade tuple with the first item negated:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda t: (-t[0], t[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks.Got it. Also string type can be negate with minus operator ?

Comment: No you can't negate a string. What you can do instead is to use the `reverse=True` parameter, e.g. `sorted(a, key=lambda t: (-t[0], t[1]), reverse=True)`

Comment: IF I want,First emphasis whose first element is smaller if collision occurs then second requirement is whose second element is lexicographically greater ?

Comment: That would be exactly the example I gave above: `sorted(a, key=lambda t: (-t[0], t[1]), reverse=True)`